# Issue Upgrading DNN 6.x to 7.4

Tags: dotnetnuke, upgrade

I am stuck with upgrading DNN from Version 6.x to version 7.4

I am using Ifnity URL Master V2.4.4 with DNN 6. Before upgrading DNN to 7.4, I have first upgraded Ifinity URL Master from 2.4 to 2.8.3 and then upgraded DNN to 7.4. while doing so I am getting below error on Default.aspx load.

```
 500 Internal Server Error
    The requested Url does not return any valid content.

    Administrators
    Change this message by configuring a specific 404 Error Page or Url for this website.

    Exception:
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    Stack Trace:
```

> at DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode() at
>   DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabModulesController.GetModules(TabInfo tab)
>   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabModulesController.GetTabModules(TabInfo
>   tab) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo.get_Modules() at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.Entities.TabInfoEx.Clone(TabInfo tab) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.Data.SqlDataProvider.GetTabs(Int32
>   portalId, Boolean includeAdminTabs, Boolean includeHostTabs,
>   Dictionary`2& customAliasTabs) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.UrlMasterController.GetTabs(Int32
>   portalId, Boolean includeStdUrls, PortalSettings portalSettings,
>   FriendlyUrlSettings settings, Dictionary2& customAliasTabsForPortal)
>   at iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.UrlMasterController.GetTabs(Int32
>   portalId, Boolean includeStdUrls, FriendlyUrlSettings settings,
>   Dictionary2& customAliasTabs) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.TabDictController.BuildTabDictionary(PathSizes&
>   pathSizes, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, Int32 buildPortalId,
>   ThreadSafeDictionary2 tabDict, Hashtable& homePageSkins,
>   ThreadSafeDictionary2& portalTabPathDictionary, Guid parentTraceId)
>   at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.TabDictController.FetchTabDictionaryLockable(Int32
>   portalId, Int32& minTabPathDepth, Int32& maxTabPathDepth, Int32&
>   minAliasPathDepth, Int32& maxAliasPathDepth, FriendlyUrlSettings
>   settings, Boolean forceRebuild, Boolean bypassCache, Guid
>   parentTraceId) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.TabDictController.FetchTabDictionary(Int32
>   portalId, Int32& minTabPathDepth, Int32& maxTabPathDepth, Int32&
>   minAliasPathDepth, Int32& maxAliasPathDepth, FriendlyUrlSettings
>   settings, Boolean forceRebuild, Boolean bypassCache, Guid
>   parentTraceId) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.RewriteController.GetTabFromDictionary(String
>   url, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, UrlAction result, Guid
>   parentTraceId) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.RewriteController.IdentifyByTabPathEx(String
>   absoluteUri, String queryString, UrlAction result, FriendlyUrlSettings
>   settings, Guid parentTraceId) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.UrlRewriteModule.CheckForRewrite(String
>   fullUrl, String querystring, UrlAction result, Boolean
>   useFriendlyUrls, NameValueCollection queryStringCol,
>   FriendlyUrlSettings settings, Boolean& isPhysicalResource, Guid
>   parentTraceId) at
>   iFinity.DNN.Modules.UrlMaster.UrlRewriteModule.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, HttpRequest request, HttpServerUtility Server, HttpResponse
>   response, Boolean useFriendlyUrls, String requestType, Uri requestUri,
>   UrlAction result, NameValueCollection queryStringCol,
>   FriendlyUrlSettings settings, Boolean allowSettingsChange, Guid
>   parentTraceId)

I am not sure cause of this error and not sure how to forward in this. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I'll ping Bruce Chapman to see if he can assist.

Answer (score -1):

I was using IFinity URL Master 2.4 as well and upgrade from 2.4 to 2.8.3 so I could upgrade DNN to 7.4.2.  I got the same problem you have.

The only way I was able to fix it was to remove IFinity URL Master completely and then upgrade to DNN 7.4.2.

In DNN 7.4.2 they have integrated IFinity URL Master into it.  Then you have to change your web.config file to use the proper URLFormat results you are looking for.  Try opening your web.config file and doing a search for URLFormat make sure it either has a value of URLFormat="humanfriendly" or URLFormat="advanced" depending on the results you wish to get.